# VueJS: How To Detect Environment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I understand how to set up environment variables as [documented here](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html), but what I'm not understanding is how to detect which environment the app is in.

Comment: You declare what environment you are targeting with CROSS-ENV flags via npm tasks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's done at build time, right? Is there a way to build once and let the code detect its environment (e.g. dev, QA, production)?

Comment: That is correct.  That said, you could create a config file that is modified per environment by your CI tool and you can read that directly and respond accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

`require()` or `import` your `*.env.js` and check `NODE_ENV`.